# Check if Username exists in range using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
     A         B        C         D       E
1            Username1
2            Username2
3            Username3
4            Username4
5            
6
```

In `Range B1:B4` I am listing all users that should be allowed to run the following VBA:

```
Sub Button_Value()
If Environ("Username") = Sheet1.Range("B1") _
Or Environ("Username") = Sheet1.Range("B2") _
Or Environ("Username") = Sheet1.Range("B3") _
Or Environ("Username") = Sheet1.Range("B4") Then
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 3
Else
Answer = MsgBox("Function not available")
End If
End Sub
```

All this works perfectly.

---

However, no I am wondering if there is a way to check if the `Username` exists in `Range B1:B4` so I do not have to use an `OR` function for each new user that I want to add?

Comment: Use `Range.Find` or `Application.Match`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments and the answers there are the following two options to solve the issue:

**Option A (Application.Match)**

```
Sub Button_Value()
If Not IsError(Application.Match(Environ("Username"), Sheet1.Range("B1:B4"), 0)) Then
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 3
Else
Answer = MsgBox("Function not available")
End If
End Sub
```

**Option B (Range.Find)**

```
Sub Button_Value()
With Sheet1
    Set Rng = Sheet.Range("B1:B4")
    If Not Rng.Find(Environ("Username")) Is Nothing Then
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 3
    Else
     Answer = MsgBox("Function not available")
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Button_Value()

    If userExists Then
       Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 3
    Else
       Msgbox "Function Not Available"
    End If

End Sub

Function userExists() as Boolean

    Dim user as String
    user = Environ("username")

    userExists = IsNumeric(Application.match(user,Sheet1.Range("B1:B4"),0))

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Range.Find` like this:

```
Dim rng As Range

With Sheet1
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    If Not rng.Find(Environ("Username")) Is Nothing Then
        .Cells(1, 1).Value = 3
    Else
        Answer = MsgBox("Function not available")
    End If
End With
```

This will also adjust to how many user names are in column `B`.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have two answers but heres a third using a dictionary to check whether the username exists:

```
            Sub test()
            Dim username As String 'declare the username
            Dim r As Range: Set r = Sheet1.Range("B1:B4") 'dim and set your range
            Dim UserNames As Scripting.Dictionary 'dim dictionary
                Set UserNameDic = New Scripting.Dictionary 'set your dictionary to a new one
            Dim x As Integer 'counter just for the dictionary value
                x = 1

            'loops through each cell in your range
            For Each u In r
                UserNameDic.Add u.Value, x 'adds your username to the dictionary
                x = x + 1
            Next

            If Not UserNameDic.Exists(Environ("username")) Then: MsgBox "Access      Denied" 'checks to see if the username exisits in the dictionary
            End Sub
```